# How to pass PHP $variables in cURL array

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I would like to pass some simple PHP variables (such as $name1 and $email1) to the following cURL block (PHP-Curl)

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\n\"email\": \"percy.jackson@gmail.com\",\n\"name\": \"Percy Jack\",}"
```

Basically replace:

- `percy.jackson2290@gmail.com` with `$email1`
- `Percy Jack` with `$name1`

Is this possible? Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to create JSON by hand, create an array and use `json_encode()`

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(["email" => $email1, "name" => $name1]),
```

For the more complex version in the comment:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
    "sequence" => 1,
    "recipients" => [
        "signers" => [
            ["email" => $email1, "name" => $name1, "recipientId" => "1", "roleName" => "Client"]
        ],
    ]
]),
```

Edited version:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
    "emailSubject" => "DocuSignAPI-CompositeTemplates",
    "emailBlurb" =>"CompositeTemplatesSample1",
    "status" => "sent",
    "compositeTemplates"=>
    ["serverTemplates"=>
     ["sequence"=>"1",
      "templateId"=>"ff32490f-58ab-4e26-a505-b32c863b2398"]],
    ["inlineTemplates"=>
     ["sequence"=>"1",
      "recipients"=>
      ["signers"=> [
       ["email" => $email1, "name" => $name1,"recipientId"=>"1","roleName"=>"Client"]]]]]]),
```

Comment: Thanks for that! There's a bit more to my problem actually, I need to include both encoded and non-encoded JSON - example below:

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>“{\"sequence\":\"1\",\"recipients\":{\"signers\":[{\"email\":\"percy.jackson2290@gmail.com\",\"name\":\"JohnDoe\",\"recipientId\":\"1\",\"roleName\":\"Client\"}]}",

Here, I do not want to use $variables for recipientId and roleName fields.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just make nested PHP arrays with whatever you want. You can hard-code strings or use variables wherever you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far, I'm learning a lot!

I tried creating the array like you showed me, but still getting an unexpected '=' syntax error at the first line (edited version above)

Comment: It should be `=>` on the first line, since this is apparently part of the argument to `curl_setopt_array`, not a variable assignment.

Comment: Now running into a different error. 
{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[API_REST.Models.v2_1.compositeTemplate]' because the type requires a JSON array....

Comment: You didn't nest the signers associative array inside another array.

Comment: Look at my version of the answer, `signers` is a 2-d array.

Answer (score 2):

As per Barmar's answer it's better to use json_encode, however if you must create the json by hand then you can do this

**Outside of CURL**

```
$postfields = '{"email": "'.$email1.'", "name": "'.$name1.'}';
var_dump(json_decode($postfields, true);
```

**In CURL**

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$postfields
```

Comment: Ah just saw your answer, will give this a try, thanks!

Comment: Hi mate, I tried your way but unfortunately keep getting a syntax error. 
I'm using http://phpfiddle.org/ to test my code but keep getting an error: {"errorCode":"INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT","message":"The email address for the recipient is invalid.


Any thoughts?

Comment: @Duke_Si1ver I've edited my answer with some tweaks to let you see the json values being passed. this should let you see the email value being passed trough.

If needed you can use a tool like POSTMAN to also test the request out of code to make sure it works as expected.(It can also generate PHP for you as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = trim(curl_exec($curl));
            $ch = curl_init();

            $post_fields = "{  \n \"socid\": \"$response\",  \n \"date\": 1492380000,  \n \"lines\":[  \n {  \n \"qty\":\"5\",  \n \"subprice\": 100,  \n \"fk_product\": \"1\",  \n \"remise_percent\": \"10\",  \n \"product_ref\": \"RPV\"  \n   \n   \n   \n }  \n ]  \n }";
            

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/crm/htdocs/api/index.php/invoices');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $post_fields );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
```

**Here as you can see.... I created one variable named $response in my case this variable contains a curl response. And in CURLOPT_POSTFIELD I passed a variable which contain curl data. There you can see how to add variable in curl**

Comment: Question is already answered. As well, it is generally better to use json encode and decode functions.